# In Qt, find out that all windows are closed, when QApplication::processEvents() is used?

Tags: c++, qt

There is a `QApplication::lastWindowClosed()` signal. The [Qt docs](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qapplication.html#lastWindowClosed) say:

```
This signal is emitted from QApplication::exec()
when the last visible primary window [...] is closed.
```

However, I used `QApplication::processEvents()` instead of `QApplication::exec()` in a loop. See this minimal example. (save as `qapp.h`, it must end on `.h`, and run `qmake -project && qmake && make`)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>

int exitprogram = 0;

class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void request_exit() {
        qDebug() << "exit requested";
        exitprogram = 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow w;
    QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()),
        &w, SLOT(request_exit()));
    w.show();
    while(!exitprogram)
    {
        app.processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 20);
    }
}
```

Is there still a good way to find out, or to even get a signal, if the last such window is being closed?

Comment: 1) `lastWindowClosed` should work fine regardless of that. Did you try it? 2) Is there any good reason to do `processEvents` instead of `exec`? It looks overcomplicated.

Comment: Add slot listening to `lastWindowClosed`, in slot set bool flag to true, check bool flag in loop. Don't see a reason not to use exec() though.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov (1) I tried it in the minimal example, just posted above. (2) is because I have to use is as part of a framework.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what you are actually trying to do is combine Qt event loop with other event loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever reason you have for using `processEvents` in place of `exec` is wrong. The two are *not* equivalent. `exec()` will, for example, process the deferred deletion events, while `processEvents` will not. As you've just found out, the `lastWindowClosed` signal is not emitted either. This should be telling you right there that you're doing it wrong.

The idiomatic Qt way of doing something each time the event loop goes for another iteration, is to use a zero-timeout timer. Those are virtual timers that do not use operating system resources, they are an internal Qt construct.

The example below illustrates the following:

1. Use of a zero-timeout timer within a `QObject`.
2. Use of the [State Machine Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html) to manage the state of the application. We have three states:

   - `sWindows` is the state when the application windows are still shown. The application is set *not* to quit on the last window being closed.
   - `sSetup` is the state reached when the last of the windows was closed. In this state we ask our `Object` to send its notification signal with the number of times it executed the zero-timeout timer. This will set the proper count in the `message` label (C++11 code) or in the `count` label (legacy code). The state machine automatically transitions to the following state.
   - `sMessage` is the state when the message labels are shown, and the application is set to quit upon the last window being closed.

The use of a state machine leads to declarative code: you tell the state machine how to behave, without implementing all of the behavior. You only have to implement the behaviors that are specific to your application and not already provided by Qt. The objects that the state machine manages can be very much decoupled, and the code that declares the behavior of the machine is cohesive - it can be all in one function, instead of being spread around. This is considered to be good software design.

Do note that the zero-timeout timer is very diligent: it will force your handler code to execute *constantly* whenever the event loop is empty. This will force 100% CPU consumption on the core where the GUI thread happens to be executing. If you have nothing to do, you should `stop()` the timer.

#### Qt 5 C++11 Code

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/close-process-19343325
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QLabel widget{"Close me :)"};
    QLabel message{"Last window was closed"};

    int counter = 0;
    auto worker = [&]{
       counter++;
    };
    QTimer workerTimer;
    QObject::connect(&workerTimer, &QTimer::timeout, worker);
    workerTimer.start(0);

    QStateMachine machine;
    QState sWindows{&machine};
    QState sSetup  {&machine};
    QState sMessage{&machine};

    sWindows.assignProperty(qApp, "quitOnLastWindowClosed", false);
    sWindows.addTransition(qApp, &QGuiApplication::lastWindowClosed, &sSetup);

    QObject::connect(&sSetup, &QState::entered, [&]{
       workerTimer.stop();
       message.setText(QString("Last window was closed. Count was %1.").arg(counter));
    });
    sSetup.addTransition(&sMessage);

    sMessage.assignProperty(&message, "visible", true);
    sMessage.assignProperty(qApp, "quitOnLastWindowClosed", true);

    machine.setInitialState(&sWindows);
    machine.start();
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

#### Qt 4/5 C++11 Code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QBasicTimer>

class Object : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QBasicTimer m_timer;
    int m_counter = 0;
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId())
            m_counter ++;
    }
public:
    Object(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject{parent} {
        m_timer.start(0, this);
    }
    Q_SLOT void stop() const {
      m_timer.stop();
      emit countedTo(m_counter);
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void countedTo(int) const;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    Object object;
    QLabel widget{"Close me :)"};
    QLabel message{"Last window was closed"};
    QLabel count;

    QStateMachine machine;
    QState sWindows{&machine};
    QState sSetup{&machine};
    QState sMessage{&machine};

    sWindows.assignProperty(qApp, "quitOnLastWindowClosed", false);
    sWindows.addTransition(qApp, "lastWindowClosed()", &sSetup);

    object.connect(&sSetup, SIGNAL(entered()), SLOT(stop()));
    count.connect(&object, SIGNAL(countedTo(int)), SLOT(setNum(int)));
    sSetup.addTransition(&sMessage);

    sMessage.assignProperty(&message, "visible", true);
    sMessage.assignProperty(&count, "visible", true);
    sMessage.assignProperty(qApp, "quitOnLastWindowClosed", true);

    machine.setInitialState(&sWindows);
    machine.start();
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and now it works. I override closeEvent

```
==> test.cpp <==
#include "windows.hpp"

int exitprogram = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow w;
    w.show();
    while(!exitprogram)
    {
        app.processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 20);
    }
}

==> test.pro <==
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
QT += widgets
INCLUDEPATH += .
HEADERS += windows.hpp

# Input
SOURCES += test.cpp

==> windows.hpp <==
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QCloseEvent>

extern int exitprogram;

class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override {
        exitprogram = 1;
        event->accept();
    }
};
```